# matrix first isomorphism problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

Let R be the set of all matrices of the form
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{pmatrix}
over $\mathbb{Q}$, such that $\ a = d\ $ and $\ b = 0\ $. Let $\ I\ $ be the subset of $\ \mathbb{R}\ $, such that $\ a = d = 0 \ . $ Show that $$R/I \cong Q.$$
[HINT : Think about defining a homomorphism...]

Help with this please, I cannot come up with a mapping, I've been trying to use the first isomorphism theorem by coming up with a ring homomorphism of $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ with my image being $\mathbb{Q}$ and kernel being $I$ but I can't come up with a mapping at all.

Comment: is $Q$ the same as $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: Consider the map $\phi:(a,b,c,d) \rightarrow (a,b,0,d)$ noting that $a=d$ and $b=0$ simplifies the problem to $\phi:(a,0,c,a) \rightarrow (a,0,0,a)$. Can you show this map is a homomorphism with the correct image and kernel?

Comment: yes it's the same

Answer (score 2):

Consider the map $$\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\c&a\end{pmatrix} \mapsto a.$$

What is the kernel of the map?

Comment: the kernal is the matrix
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & b \\
c & d  \\
\end{pmatrix}
is that right?

Comment: no. What is the subspace? I rewrote the subspace with the conditions for being in the subspace.

Comment: ahh, the subpace is in the question isn't it with I and a = d = 0 ?

Comment: yes${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: so what do you mean what is the subspace?

Comment: $R$ is the space, I was referring to the subspace of all matrices $a,b,c,d$. Anyhow. Do you see the point? When is the map $0$? What does that mean?

Comment: so the that map is 0 at a = 0?

Comment: Yes, but if $a=0$ in the image, what is the preimage (the kernel) of $a=0$ under this map?

Comment: \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}

Comment: No. For example $$\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$$ is in the kernel

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you check $R$ is a ring and $I$ is an ideal of $R$ first. Then find a map $f$ from $R$ to $\mathbb{Q}$. Show that $f$ is a ring homomorphism, $f$ is surjective, and $\ker f=I$.